# How to change image from Skybox Material in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm new in Unity..I'm trying to change Image from a Material that is Mobile/Skybox with Script.

Comment: Can you show us any code you've already tried to use? If you haven't attempted to solve this problem on your own yet, research a bit and code your own solution before asking here for help. Googling "change skybox material unityscript" gave me an answer to your question by the first result.

Comment: I just want to change the skybox images with coding...

Answer (score 0):

have a read of

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Skybox.html

and

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Skybox.html

they're good starting points to get to the bottom of sorting out your issues :)

Comment: No problem, looking at the documentation is always a good place to start when trying to code :)